# Generating .framework file using Xcode BOT

Tags: xcode, frameworks, continuous-integration, bots, osx-server

I'm trying to create a bot for my project with an **iOS framework** as target.
What's missing for me is any pointer or documentation that explains how to expose the output framework in a way that team members will be able to download the framework from the OSX Server.

The current web page exposed by the Xcode service only grants access to full archives.

The only way I see around this problem is setting up my own web server and implementing a custom script. 
Is there any project out these that implements anything similar?

Plz help if u have any idea.

Thanks